# Return two Hashset from a Java method

Tags: java, hash

I have this piece of code here that I want to transform in a method.

The problem is that I need the result of both hashes

How can I create a method that will return those two hashset (allPeopleFromTable and visibleInfo) ?

```
public method foo: 

Set<People> allPeopleFromTable = new HashSet<>();
        Set<People> visibleInfo = new HashSet<>();
        for (ResultSet rs : resultSets) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                final Table people = new Table(rs);

                allPeopleFromTable.add(people);
                if (isVisible(people)) {
                    visibleInfo.add(people);
                }
            }
        }

then in the main method I want to do
visibleInfo = getfoo(...)
allPeopleFromTable = getfoo (..)
```

Comment: Return a `List<Set<People>>`. Or make a custom object that contains two `Set` and return that.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? How can I add my two separate sets in this one list of sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to pass them into the method:

```
void foo(Set<People> allPeopleFromTable, Set<People> visibleInfo) {
    // add items to sets
}
```

Another option is return a list of sets:

```
List<Set<People>> foo() {
    // create sets
    return Arrays.asList(allPeopleFromTable, visibleInfo);
}
```

Or you can return a tuple class, like `Entry`:

```
Map.Entry<Set<People>, Set<People>> foo() {
    // create sets
    return Map.entry(allPeopleFromTable, visibleInfo);
}
```

The most "proper" approach would be to wrap them in a custom class.

```
record PeopleSets(Set<People> allPeopleFromTable, Set<People> visibleInfo) {}

PeopleSets foo() {
    // create sets
    return new PeopleSets(allPeopleFromTable, visibleInfo);
}
```

This example uses [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/language/records.html), but you can use a conventional class if you're on an older version of Java.

Comment: Thank you. If I use the second approach I would get the value by doing Set<People> visible = foo.get(0) ?

Comment: Yes. The manual indexing makes it arguably the weakest solution here. But it can be useful if you need to return multiple sets, especially if the number is variable.